# How to define class variables that aren't flat, with default values

Tags: typescript

Defining a flat class like this works just fine:

```js
class Test {
 company_name: string = "";
 company_id: number = 0;
 company_website: string = "";
}
```

If I do `let product = new Test()` it all works as expected, and `product` is also loaded up with the default values.

How can I achieve the same thing, but on class variables that aren't flat? Ideally it should work something like in this example (which fails):

```js
class Test {
  companyData: {
    company_name: string = "";
    company_id: number = 0;
    company_website: string = "";
  }
  productData: {
    category_id: number = 0;
    product_name: string = "";
    price: {
      price_in: number = 0;
      price_out: number = 0;
    }
  }
}
```

The error in VSCode is `A type literal property cannot have an initializer`. In my use-case it's important that all the variables are set, and that I can assign them with a default value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are defining the `Types`, and not setting the `values` of the `properties` (or something in between, the syntax is incorrect anyhow).

Try this instead:

```
class Test {
  public companyData = {
    company_name: '',
    company_id: 0,
    company_website: ''
  };
  public productData = {
    category_id: 0,
    product_name: '',
    price: {
      price_in: 0,
      price_out: 0
    }
  };
}
```

If you want to also have them `Typed` (which you should), use interfaces:

```
interface CompanyData {
  company_name: string;
  company_id: number;
  company_website: string;
}

interface ProductData {
  category_id: number;
  product_name: string;
  price: Price;
}

interface Price {
  price_in: number;
  price_out: number;
}

class Test {
  public companyData: CompanyData = {
    company_name: '',
    company_id: 0,
    company_website: ''
  };
  public productData: ProductData = {
    category_id: 0,
    product_name: '',
    price: {
      price_in: 0,
      price_out: 0
    }
  };
}
```